# Loading dependency over Composer with defined repository in dependency

Tags: dependencies, repository, composer-php

I have project `projectAlfa` with my dependency `my/project-beta`. But `my/project-beta` has dependency `otherProject` without *composer.json*. So i defined repository with type `package`  in `my/project-beta`.

**Project Alfa** *composer.json*

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "http://github.com/my/project-Beta"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "my/project-beta": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

**Project Beta** *composer.json*

```
{
  "name": "my/project-beta",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "other/project",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "http://github.com/Other/Project",
          "reference": "master"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "other/project": "*"
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

If i run `composer install` on `projectAlfa` then dependencies is not loaded, because:

`my/project-beta dev-master requires other/project * -> no matching package found`

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible solutions.

First, Composer does ignore any additional repositories that are not part of the core composer.json file of your main project. You can however repeat all these mentions there and allow Composer to then find this third party dependency without a composer.json file.

Repeating all the repositories you get code from is not the best solution, but a quick one for a small scope.

The second solution would be to create a lokal Satis repository that contains all the metadata from private repositories that are unknown on packagist.org. You'd still have to manually add the link to this Satis repository URL, but this really is the same everywhere, and if you update something in Satis, all projects will instantly benefit from it without having to change something inside of them.